# ASP.Net Razor MVC Bootstrap Login Modal Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

Using Bootstrap in my Razor page, I am opening a modal window:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navbar-offcanvas" data-canvas="body">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">
                <img src="assets/img/logo-header.png" alt="Alternate Text for Image">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-offcanvas offcanvas navmenu-fixed-left">
            <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">eServices</a>
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalSignup" data-backdrop="static">New Here?</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogin" data-backdrop="static">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <p>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login to MyApplication</h3>
                </p>
            </div>

                @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-group @Html.ValidationErrorFor(m => m.Username, "has-error has-feedback")">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.FormTextBoxFor(p => p.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @if (!Html.IsValid(m => m.Username))
                            {
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group @Html.ValidationErrorFor(m => m.Password, "has-error has-feedback")">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.FormPasswordFor(p => p.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @if (!Html.IsValid(m => m.Password))
                            {
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, string.Empty, new { @class = "test" }, "span")
                    <div class=" pull-right">
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Forms.ButtonSignin</button>
                        </p>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your username?", "ForgotUsername")
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I have is that, for example, I entered an incorrect username/password combination, the form validates, but the modal window closes. Is there a way to re-open the modal window after the form has posted if the validation triggered an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property named `IsModalShown` i.e.

```
public class AModel
{
    public bool IsModalShown { get; set; }
}
```

Render this as a hidden for in your view i.e.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsModalShown)
```

When the modal is opened set the hidden value to true, this will enable the modal state to be posted back to the controller action i.e.

```
$('#modalLogin').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#IsModalShown').val(true);
})
```

Please note the above will depend on the version of bootstrap you are using but there are other docs on the official site

Then add the following to your view that automatically pops it up

```
$(function(){
    @if(Model.IsModalShown)
    {
        $('#signin_modal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but didn't have a model in view. Posting my solution, in case it would help someone. I wanted to show an error message stored in `TempData` (in case of wrong login/password combination, on which Batuta was asking).

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string login, string password)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(login, password))
        {
            // something
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["message-error"] = "Wrong combination";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Showing the message in modal window:

```
@if (TempData["message-error"] != null)
{
@TempData["message-error"]
}
```

Opening modal in index:

```
@if (TempData["message-error"] != null)
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>
}
```

Maybe not that clean, but works for me.